# Hide create new account tab

Tags: forms, users

How to hide Create new account and Request new password tabs in user login form? I use Drupal 7. I use custom theme. Maybe in template.php file some function?

You can see my page - http://broceni.garm.lv/

Answer (score 1):

The [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module will do it for you without having to write a single line of code:

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering, hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab labels.

Comment: Ok, I installed it. In admin/config/tabtamer is config. Why active is only comment/% and node/% ? user/% user/%/edit user taxonomy/term/% is not active? I cant do changes on user login form.

Comment: Ah yes it seems there's [a bug](http://drupal.org/node/1440702)...just change line 309 in tabtamer.module to `'#collapsed' => FALSE` and it'll work :)

Comment: I do that and I get some more active things, but something is wrong with that module.. I change under user. I put hidden that tabs, but dont see efect.

Comment: I want remove links, that appears after user login form input fields. I want button Log in before that 2 links